# logback elasticsearch appender missing index in Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, logback, elk

I have a Spring Boot application.

I want to send my logs directly from logback to elasticsearch. I'm using Logback Elasticsearch Appender (https://github.com/internetitem/logback-elasticsearch-appender)

The problem is that the index is not created in Elasticsearch. The File appender is working as expected and there are no errors in the logs or anything that shows a misconfiguration.

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>
            myApp.log
        </file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>
                myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>
                15
            </maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                [%d] [%thread] [%-5level] [%class.%method] [user=%mdc{user:-n/d}] - %msg%n%ex{20}
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
  
    <appender name="ELASTIC" class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
        <url>http://localhost:9200/_bulk</url>
        <index>dev_myapp-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
        <type>logback</type>
        <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
        <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize> <!-- optional (default 104857600) -->
        <maxRetries>3</maxRetries> <!-- optional (default 3) -->
        <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout> <!-- optional (in ms, default 30000) -->
        <sleepTime>250</sleepTime> <!-- optional (in ms, default 250) -->
        <rawJsonMessage>false</rawJsonMessage> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <includeMdc>false</includeMdc> <!-- optional (default false) -->
        <maxMessageSize>-1</maxMessageSize> <!-- optional (default -1 -->
<!--        <authentication class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" />  optional -->
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>severity</name>
                <value>%level</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>thread</name>
                <value>%thread</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>stacktrace</name>
                <value>%ex</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>logger</name>
                <value>%logger{16}.%method</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>server-time</name>
                <value>%date{ISO8601, America/Costa_Rica}</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <name>Content-Type</name>
                <value>text/plain</value>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </appender>
 
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ELASTIC" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.myCompany.myApp" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.hql" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask" level="DEBUG"/>

</configuration>
```

I'd expect to see dev_myapp-2022-01-20 in my local Elasticsearch index, but it's not there.

Elasticsearch is running locally:
curl localhost:9200

```
{
  "name" : "ubuntu-dev-stage-services",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "B0K_ThdDTlWftcVw23_NKA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.16.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "4e6e4eab2297e949ec994e688dad46290d018022",
    "build_date" : "2022-01-06T23:43:02.825887787Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And this are the index in the instance:
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices

```
green open .geoip_databases                y1revQR7SyWHJIxnAq0z7w 1 0  42     0 40.3mb 40.3mb
green open .kibana_7.16.3_001              zjnnLKjXT362iQdFnXPsHQ 1 0 279    25  2.4mb  2.4mb
green open .apm-custom-link                t8-PvRWaTpSd1n2xuT8tYA 1 0   0     0   226b   226b
green open .apm-agent-configuration        hx8SsYzkTDqkEPpA7aZcvg 1 0   0     0   226b   226b
green open .kibana_task_manager_7.16.3_001 H-Kjao4hRLW45PmEMTvnGw 1 0  17 11520  1.6mb  1.6mb
green open .tasks                          Xp2ezFegRo-jzjK4UfUTpQ 1 0   6     0 28.9kb 28.9kb
```

**EDIT**

I was able to make it work by using Elasticsearch 5. I'm not sure but looks like the appender does not work with Elasticsearch 7

Comment: There is nothing in elasticsearch logs? Also, is this the name of the index that you are trying to create: `dev_myApp-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}`? If so, you will need to change it, you can only have lowercase letters, it can't be `dev_myApp-*`, but it can be `dev_myapp-*`.

Comment: There is nothing in elasticsearch logs. The index is not showing when I hit curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices. To confirm, the index in logback.xml is all lower case. I'm updating the post.

Comment: From the documentation of the appender I would suggest that you change `errorsToStderr` to `true`, to see if you are having any errors in the communication. Without any log error from the application, and any log from elasticsearch side, it is not possible to know what is happening.

Comment: I changed both `errorsToStderr` and `logsToStderr ` to `true` but still nothing. I see no difference when refreshing indices from elasticsearch or when `tail -f` the log file.

Comment: I don't have Logstash installed, but I understand it's not needed since `com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender` sends data directly to Elasticsearch

Comment: Elasticsearch 7 does not support the _type field anymore. try to remove the line "<type>tester</type>" from your logback configuration file